# What is the origin of the terminology 'spin up/down'?

Tags: terminology, quantum-mechanics

In my research area one seminal reference is [H. Bethe, ''Zur Theorie der Metalle'', Z. Phys. **71** 205 (1931)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01341708), see also the [English translation by T. C. Dorlas (2009)](https://homepages.dias.ie/dorlas/Papers/Bethe.pdf). On page 206 of the original reference we read

> Solange von der Wechselwirkung abgesehen wird, gibt es für jedes Atom
>   zwei Zustände mit gleicher Energie: Der Spin des Leuchtelektrons kann
>   nach rechts oder nach links zeigen.

Thus it seems that at the time, at least in the German-speaking scientific community, the terminology spin 'left' and 'right', rather than 'up' and 'down, was used for the two basis vectors of the spin-1/2 irrep of $su(2)$. Was this indeed common practice? If so, was this the original terminology used? And why and by whom was it changed to 'up' and 'down'?

---

NB. I can speculate that the following happened. 'Left' and 'right' may originate from the Stern--Gerlach experiment, of course depending on the direction of the external magnetic field in the original experiment. Later on, '$\leftarrow$' and '$\rightarrow$' might then have been replaced by the more compact '$\uparrow$' and '$\downarrow$' for typographical reasons.

Comment: You may have already seen this, but this paper on arXiv titled "A Short History of Spin" may be of some help.  Please see : https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.5016 . The paper states that Stern-Gerlach observed deflection as either up or down and there is no reference to the left/right terminology.

Comment: @NickR Thanks, I did not know that. It only makes Bethe's terminology more surprising, then.

Comment: Note that Bethe’s paper has an “official” translation in his *Selected works* ([1997](https://books.google.com/books?id=5baAG1WqgYQC&pg=PA159&dq=left)). Unlike Dorlas, it renders “Linksspin” and “Rechtsspin” as “left-handed” and “right-handed”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bethe is quoting and following **Felix Bloch**, who said left/right in ([1929](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01340281); [1930, p. 207](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01339661)). But I don’t think this was ever “common practice”. Stern, in his original Stern–Gerlach paper, drew the magnetic field $\mathfrak H$ and quantized angular momentum component $\mathfrak m_z$ vertically ([1921, p. 251](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01332793)):

$\hspace{11em}$[image]

In doing so, he followed (and quoted) Sommerfeld’s *Atombau und Spektrallinien* (2nd ed., [1921, pp. 408-411](https://archive.org/stream/atombauundspekt00sommgoog#page/n429)) and ultimately Sommerfeld’s original [“spatial quantization”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_quantization) paper ([1916, pp. 29-32](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.19163561702/abstract)):

[image]
[image]

(If Fig. 6 looks like a horizontal component is being quantized, it’s only because the lines represent the orbital plane, not the angular momentum vector perpendicular to it; Sommerfeld didn’t switch to picturing the latter until *Atombau*’s 5th edition ([1931; 1934 translation, p. 123](http://edition-open-access.de/studies/2/7/#5)):

$\hspace{50em}$[image].)

It’s true that the Stern–Gerlach *experimental* magnetic field was apparently horizontal ([1922](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01326983), [1924](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.19243791602/abstract)). But they didn’t call it left/right any more than front/back or up/down; and the subsequent theories of Heisenberg–Jordan ([1926, p. 266](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01397100)), Pauli ([1927, p. 605](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01397326)), Dirac ([1928, p. 620](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1928.0023)) and expositions by Weyl ([1928, p. 65](https://books.google.com/books?id=ebjPAAAAMAAJ&dq=Stern+Gerlach)), Dirac ([1930, p. 152](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.177580#page/n162)), Wigner ([1931, p. 238](https://books.google.com/books?id=X9XzBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA238&dq=Z-Richtung)) or Bethe himself ([1933, p. 276](https://books.google.com/books?id=pQOdBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA276&dq=z-Richtung)) all quantized in the $z$ direction!

**Edit:**
As to the title question, my guess is that the standard terms were “positive spin” and “negative spin” from around the time of Sommerfeld–Bethe ([1933](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z47KBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA588&dq=positiven)) and until maybe the early 1950s, when “spin up” and “spin down” began to appear, with and then without quotes, in references like Blatt–Weisskopf ([1952](https://books.google.com/books?id=CTrOAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22We+shall+refer+to+these+two+possibilities%22)), Kittel ([1953](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ag5RAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22spin+up%22)), Bethe–Maximon ([1954](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=62020)), Bethe–Salpeter ([1957](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=96526)).